# Python, scipy : minimize multivariable function in integral expression

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

how can I minimize a function (uncostrained), respect a[0] and a[1]?
example (this is a simple example for I uderstand scipy, numpy and py):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import *
from scipy.optimize import *
def function(a):
    return(quad(lambda t: ((np.cos(a[0]))*(np.sin(a[1]))*t),0,3))
```

i tried:

```
l=np.array([0.1,0.2])
res=minimize(function,l, method='nelder-mead',options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp':    True})
```

but I get errors.
I get the results in matlab.

any idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: *"...I get errors."*  Please show the complete error message.

Comment: Is `chirplet` the same as `function`? Also, do you want the function to be integrated over `l` and vary `a` to minimize the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, because you haven't included enough information in the question for anyone to really know what the problem is.  Whenever you ask a question about code that generates an error, always include the complete error message in the question.  Ideally, you should include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to reproduce the problem.   Currently, you define `function`, but later you use the undefined function `chirplet`.  That makes it a little bit harder for anyone to understand your problem.

Having said that...

[`scipy.integrate.quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) returns two values: the estimate of the integral, and an estimate of the absolute error of the integral.  It looks like you haven't taken this into account in `function`.   Try something like this:

```
def function(a):
    intgrl, abserr = quad(lambda t: np.cos(a[0])*np.sin(a[1])*t, 0, 3)
    return intgrl
```

Comment: I would also say, also include the actual code that caused the problem. I think that the OP calls **function** in his/her code rather than **chirplet**.

Comment: @BillBell Yup.  I added a suggestion to include a MCVE.

Comment: Warren Weckesser I'am sorry, you're right. The problem was that you've identified you, thx for solution ;)